A reference error occurs when adding a namespace with the @using keyword
I get the following error when adding namespace with @using:

The type or namespace name 'CreateNewOnMetadataUpdateAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices' (are you missing an assembly reference?)


I moved the _ViewImports.cshtml file into the Views folder. I researched on the internet many times but could not solve the problem.
Is the problem really something simple? Or is there an issue with VS Code? I would really appreciate if you can help.

I know this. The _ViewImports.cshtml file is in the Views folder as shown in the screenshot. But why does @using give an error? I do not understand this.

Your reference seems to be correct. Sometimes, Visual Studio may encounter a bug and build an old version of your code.
Please try running the dotnet restore command. If that doesn't work, you can simply delete the bin and obj folders in your project directory, and re-build the solution. This will force Visual Studio to recreate these folders, thereby ensuring it is up to date with your latest changes.
There are some threads that you may want to look to if it doesn't work, like this one:

Razor The type or namespace could not be found


Thank you for your answer, but it didn't work.

I ran the project with Visual Studio 2022. I didn't get any errors. The problem is with Visual Studio Code. But Visual Studio Code is very fast. I wish there wasn't such a problem.
